# What’s the antecedent for this which?

Tags: phrases, antecedents

> A breeze ruffled the neat hedges of Privet Drive, **which** lay silent and
>   tidy under the inky sky, **(1)** the very last place you would expect
>   astonishing things to happen. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What’s the antecedent for *which*?
Is the noun phrase (1) modifying Privet Drive?

Comment: I think this is Too Localised or Not A Real Question. Grammatically speaking *which* modifies the preceding noun phrase. It's entirely a matter of logical interpretation (nothing to do with language as such) whether what lays "silent and tidy" is *Privet Drive* or ***the neat hedges of** Privet Drive*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But *which* preceding noun phrase? For the learner it is important to understand when syntactic and when semantic considerations govern - which are both linguistic considerations.

Comment: @StoneyB: But unless I'm much mistaken, OP *knows* the basic rule that a pronoun refers back to an earlier noun phrase. If not, he probably wouldn't be asking us to identify ***the** antecedent*. I just think this is a pointless *"How long is a piece of string?"* sort of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, the antecedent of **which** must be one of three things:

1. A breeze ruffled the neat hedges of Privet Drive (the entire *independent clause*)
2. the neat hedges of Privet Drive (a *noun phrase*)
3. Privet Drive (a smaller *noun phrase*)

To figure out which choice is best, just ask yourself which one makes sense:

- In this case, **1** doesn't make any sense.  For **1** to make sense, the relative clause would have to comment on the proposition, as in the following example: "A breeze ruffled the neat hedges of Privet Drive, *which I found quite surprising, as I'd previously removed all the air from Britain*."
- Likewise, **2** doesn't make a lot of sense.  It's true that I wouldn't expect neat hedges to be a place where astonishing things happen, but usually hedges aren't considered *places* at all.  This interpretation doesn't seem very likely.
- **3** is a much better choice.  Privet Drive is a place, and the later noun phrase uses the word "place" explicitly, so it makes the most sense.  Reading further should reinforce this choice: the story isn't taking place in the hedges.  Rather, it's taking place on Privet Drive.

Ruling out 1 and 2, we can conclude that the antecedent must be **Privet Drive**.

Comment: I somewhat doubt this question is being asked in good faith, to be honest. Granted, a *breeze* can't *lay silent and tidy*, but your alternatives #2 and #3 are both at least sufficiently credible that it's pointless arbitrating between them unless ELL is to become a Lit Crit site.

Answer (score 2):

*Which* is referred to *Privet Drive*, for which "the very last place you would expect astonishing things to happen" is a noun phrase describing it.